# phpMyAdmin export vs mysqldump

Tags: mysql

Is it more reliable to use `mysqldump` instead of phpMyAdmin's export for distributing a database structure? (along with some initial data)

I need to make sure mysql dump works on all version of mysql 5. Are there any options in mysql dump for compatibility mode?

Comment: If the MySQL dump was generated from a server with version 5.1.23 and above it will be compatible with any version of MySQL are you experiencing any issues with it or using an older version? You also have [compatible mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible) for other RDBMS and mysql3/4

Comment: I am not having problems, I am just wondering if I generate in mysql 5 that will will work with all version of mysql > 5

Comment: As long as it is 5.1.23 and above yes as 5.1.22 or .21 had a bug.

Comment: @Prix Could you point me to the document from mysql that states this feature of compatibility of mysqldumps?

Comment: It'll be interesting to have an answer to this question.